# Finding what f is knowing its derivate.

Tags: calculus

How can one find the function $f$ by knowing some of its properites for $f'$

so if we let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, with $f(0)=0$ which is differentiable in $(0,1)$. $f'$ is symmetrical at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and the area which is bounded by the x-axis and the part of $f'$ which lies over the x-axis which is $\frac{1}{3}$, while the area that is bounded by the x-axis and the part that $f'$ which is located under the x-axis is $\frac{1}{12}$

is it then possible to find what $f$ is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember there are infinite points (i.e. elements in a Hilbert Space member) in the $[0,1]$ interval, thus no, giving a finite number of clue points about $f$, its integrals or its derivatives, is simply not enough.

Unless you dramatically constraint the Hilbert Space to, lets say, polynomials with $n$ free parameters, with $n$ the number of clues you are giving, and assuming these clues impose independent constraints.

Comment: Lets say we constrain the Hilbert Space, how would one go about finding $f$ then?

Comment: If you constraint the space to the subset $f(x)=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$, then you calculate all the integrals and derivatives, as your question request, and evaluate every conditions. If you have 4 numerical clues, and your function template has 4 variables, you can find the parameters under that subset easily, i.e. the values of a,b,c,d. But you must know that expression beforehand....

Comment: ah, what if I know what the graph looks like? Or if I have to find say $f(1)$ for example?

Comment: Yes, you can sketch a graph and do an approximate based on that, though beside the constraints, you will never be sure if the function pass a little below that point, or a little above another...